# Passing variable in hooks and filter

Tags: theme-development, filters, hooks

I was trying to pass variables in filtes. This works perfectly for me.

```
class my_class {
 function my_class() {
    add_filter('wp_list_categories', array(&$this,'cat_count_span'));
 }
function cat_count_span($links) {
   $links = str_replace('</a> (', '</a> <span>', $links);
   $links = str_replace(')', '</span>', $links);
   return $links;
   }
 } 
new my_class();
```

But now I want to execute the filter based on theme options value.
Say I have my theme option value `$search = ot_get_option('search_header');` 
based on this value I want to add filter and also controll the output.Like this way

```
class my_class {
   function my_class() {
     add_filter('wp_list_categories', array(&$this,'cat_count_span'));
   }
 function cat_count_span($links) {
   $search = ot_get_option('search_header');
   if ($search === 'on') {
   $links = str_replace('</a> (', '</a> <span>', $links);
   $links = str_replace(')', '</span>', $links);
   return $links;
   }
   }
 } 
new my_class();
```

Comment: Move the return outside the conditional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very sure why you would want to do this is a class, as you can simply make use of spaghetti filter function here.

If you really need to do this in a class, there are a few issues with your class

- We are moving towards PHP 7, and WordPress has eventually woke up and also moving toward PHP 7 now with its classes. PHP 4 type constructors died with the dinosaurs and should not be used. **Never ever** try to support people that are using EOL'ed PHP versions. Don't compromise performance and security to support EOL'ed versions. Note, PHP 4 type constructors are depreciated in PHP 7

> **Warning**
>
> Old style constructors are DEPRECATED in PHP 7.0, and will be removed in a future version. You should always use __construct() in new code.

- Constructors should do class initialization, and should not perform task. You should not use constructors to add filters or actions. Move that outside your class
- It is good practice to name public methods `public function function_name()`, and not just `function function_name()`
- In general here, a filter should always return something. Your filter is failing because if your condition fails, your filter don't have a fallback as it returns nothing

### CLASS METHOD

You can rewrite your class to something like this: (***NOTE:** Since we are well passed PHP5.3, it is good to make use of [namespacing when constructing classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php). There are many good tutorials about this subject*)

```
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * Class instance.
     *
     * @see get_instance()
     * @type object
     */
    protected static $instance = NULL;
    
    // Access the working instance of the class
    public static function get_instance()
    {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }
    
    // Use the __construct() method for constructors
    public function __construct() 
    {
        // Add initialization here. Do not add add_filter/add_action here
    }

    public function CatCountSpan( $links )
    {
        $search = ot_get_option('search_header');

        if ($search === 'on') {
            $links = str_replace('</a> (', '</a> <span>', $links);
            $links = str_replace(')', '</span>', $links);
        }
   
        // Move the return statement outside the condition
        return $links;
    }
} // end of class
```

You can then add your filter as follow, outside the class

```
add_filter(
    'wp_list_categories',
    [MyClass::get_instance(), 'CatCountSpan']
);
```

### GREAT RESOURCES ON-SITE

- [add_action reference a class](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48085/add-action-reference-a-class)
- [Where is the best place to use add_filter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80267/where-is-the-best-place-to-use-add-filter)

### NORMAL SPAGHETTI USING CLOSURES

As I said, I do not really the see the usefulness of a class here, I would probably just use a normal filter function

```
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', function ( $links )
{
    $search = ot_get_option('search_header');

    if ($search === 'on') {
        $links = str_replace('</a> (', '</a> <span>', $links);
        $links = str_replace(')', '</span>', $links);
    }

    // Move the return statement outside the condition
    return $links;
});
```