# Must use Plugin not updating HTML code in head

Tags: plugins, php, mu-plugins

I am trying to insert code in `head` tag through MU Plugin. I don't know why `head` tag and `init` is not updating by using `add_action('wp_head', 'my_function')` and `add_action('init', 'my_function2')`. My code example as following:

```
<?php
    class some_code        
    {
        public
        function __construct()
        {
            add_action('init', 'change_url');
            add_action('wp_head', 'print_header_scripts');
    }

    function change_url()
    {
        $domain_name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $country_code = get_country_code();
        if ($country_code == "PK")
            {
                header("location: http://///////////////");
                exit();
            }
        else if ($country_code == "AU" && $domain_name !== "au.cacricketbats.com")
        {


              header("location: https:///////////////////" . 
                parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
                exit();
            }
        }

        function print_header_scripts()
        {
    ?> /***************************************************************************/
            <script>
                (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
                })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

                ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
                ga('send', 'pageview');
            </script>"
            <?php
        }
    }
        $myCode = new some_code();
        ?>
```

I've also check that `wp_head()` is being called in `header.php` of my WordPress theme. Kindly help me thanks.

Comment: Check this question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48085/add-action-reference-a-class

Comment: I've already checked that and I've hooked through function. But I haven't got any result.:(

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by adding 
        `$myCode -> change_url();` and
    `add_action('wp_head', array($myCode, 'print_header_scripts'));`

```
<?php
class some_code        
{

function change_url()
{
    $domain_name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $country_code = get_country_code();
    if ($country_code == "PK")
        {
            header("location: http://///////////////");
            exit();
        }
    else if ($country_code == "AU" && $domain_name !== "au.cacricketbats.com")
    {


          header("location: https:///////////////////" . 
            parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
            exit();
        }
    }

    function print_header_scripts()
    {
?> /***************************************************************************/
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>"
        <?php
    }
}
    $myCode = new some_code();
    $myCode -> change_url();
add_action('wp_head', array($myCode, 'print_ga_scripts'));
    ?>
```