# Using add action for class with construct

Tags: actions, oop

i have this i answer in reference but seems have upvoted by many https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/48094/145078

but not sure why it is not working for me..

in answer

```
    class MyClass {
         function __construct() {
              add_action( 'init',array( $this, 'getStuffDone' ) );
         }
         function getStuffDone() {
              // .. This is where stuff gets done ..
         }
    }
    $var = new MyClass();
```

don't i have to set the visibility?

```
namespace NS{
class MyClass {
     public function __construct() {
          add_action( 'init',array( $this, 'getStuffDone' ) );
     }
     public function getStuffDone() {
          // .. This is where stuff gets done ..
     }
}
}

$var = new MyClass();
```

above code does not works for me, is not correct or any mistake from my side?

but this code works fine

```
add_action('init',function(){
 $lat = new \NS\MyClass();
 $lat->getStuffDone(); //Sorry not $lath
});
```

i am calling the class file as require get_template_directory(). /myfolder/class/MyClass.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> above code does not works for me, is not correct or any mistake from
>   my side?

And it didn't work for me either. Because it throws this fatal error:

> PHP Fatal error:  No code may exist outside of namespace {} in ...

And that's because the PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php) says:

> No PHP code may exist outside of the namespace brackets except for an
>   opening declare statement.

So your code could be fixed in two ways:

1. Use the *non-bracketed* syntax.

   ```
   <?php
   namespace NS;

   class MyClass {
        public function __construct() {
             add_action( 'init',array( $this, 'getStuffDone' ) );
        }
        public function getStuffDone() {
             // .. This is where stuff gets done ..
        }
   }

   $var = new MyClass();
   ```
2. Put global code (or the `$var = new MyClass();`) inside a namespace statement (`namespace {}`) with no namespace. *Note though*, that you need to use `NS\MyClass` instead of just `MyClass`.

   ```
   <?php
   // No code here. (except `declare`)

   namespace NS {

       class MyClass {
            public function __construct() {
                 add_action( 'init',array( $this, 'getStuffDone' ) );
            }
            public function getStuffDone() {
                 // .. This is where stuff gets done ..
            }
       }
   }
   // No code here. (except another `namespace {...}`)

   namespace {
       $var = new NS\MyClass();
   }
   // No code here. (except another `namespace {...}`)
   ```

### UPDATE

Ok, this is what I have in `wp-content/themes/my-theme/includes/MyClass.php`:

```
<?php
namespace NS;

class MyClass {
     public function __construct() {
          add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'getStuffDone' ) );
          add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'test' ) );
     }

     public function getStuffDone() {
          error_log( __METHOD__ . ' was called' );
     }

     public function test( $content ) {
          return __METHOD__ . ' in the_content.<hr>' . $content;
     }
}

$var = new MyClass();
```

And I'm including the file from `wp-content/themes/my-theme/functions.php`:

```
require_once get_template_directory() . '/includes/MyClass.php';
```

Try that out and see if it works for you, because it worked well for me:

- You'd see `NS\MyClass::test in the_content.` in the post content (just visit any single post).
- You'd see `NS\MyClass::getStuffDone was called` added in the `error_log` file or `wp-content/debug.log` if you enabled [`WP_DEBUG_LOG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG).

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer ,  the answer has to work but i am making some mistake some where ..not able to figure out where i am making that mistake.. i am calling the file in functions.php as `require get_template_directory(). /myfolder/class/MyClass.php` can that be a problem..sorry for not mentioning this before...

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you! And I hope you don't mind I edited the answer. (You can see the revision for the edit reason) Also, what was your mistake? You could edit your question, or write an answer, or just reply here.

Comment: i tried with new files and it works correctly as per your answer but in actual i was having problems with woocommece class that i created it is still not solved but your answer is correct

Comment: I see. If the problem is still there, you can post the class code on Pastebin, and I might be able to help you solve/identify the problem.

Comment: Hi ..this is the function i am trying to use `init` : https://pastebin.com/T5LVrrx9  , the  `add_action('init',function()` only works for me

Comment: If you mean it doesn't work when called from `init`, then try a later action like `wp_loaded` or `template_redirect`. But I'm really not sure what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

1. don't i have to set the visibility?

You don't have to, but you should. Class properties and methods without visibility will be implied to be "public", but it's best practice to be explicit when defining members.

2. above code does not works for me, is not correct or any mistake from my side?

Your code looks fine. I did notice that your class uses the `admin_init` hook, but your closure example uses `init`. Bear in mind that `admin_init` *only fires in the WordPress admin*, and not on the front-end. It could be possible that your code isn't hooking in at the right time, but that's unlikely.

Try this:

```
class MyClass {
    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function hooks() {
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'doAdminTest' ) );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'doGeneralTest' ) );
    }

    public function doAdminTest() {
        die( 'We are in the admin area.' );
    }

    public function doGeneralTest() {
        die( 'We are in the init hook.' );
    }
}

$var = new MyClass();

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $var, 'hooks' ) );
```

Now, if you go to /wp-admin/ or your front-end, you should get the result of `doGeneralTest`. If you comment out the `add_action` line for `init`, you should see the result of `doAdminTest` at /wp-admin/

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer , it is still not working for me , construct method seems very cool, i am trying to have have frontend(init) with my class..only last method is working me as mentioned in question. i am using namespace will that be problem?