# Redirect not work

Tags: redirect, headers

I have class:

```
 class users{

        public function __construct(){

           add_action('do_redirect', 'redirect'); 

        }

        public function redirect(){
                $url = get_site_url(null, '/welcome', 'https');  
                wp_redirect( $url );
                exit;
            }  

        public function some_function(){
        do_action('do_redirect');

    }

}
```

I get error :

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'redirect' not found or invalid function name.
```

If I  use only `wp_redirect()` i get error for headers.

How i must change this, because i fell I do something wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the following answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48085/add-action-reference-a-class#answer-48094. It explains how to call add_action with class methods.

Comment: I change to "add_action('do_redirect',array( $this, 'redirect' ));" and works but now i still headers error

Comment: Maybe you take a look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F). Btw error with headers? what kind of error, what does it say. Please don't expect us to guess what errors you get, show them by adding them to your question (please update also the code now with your correction)

Comment: At what point are you initiating the `users` class, or calling  `new users()`?

Comment: I have warning: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:242) in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1251

Comment: I initiate `users` class in first file in plugin and I use `new users()`.

Comment: Where/when are you calling `some_function`

Comment: redirect is the name of a global wordpress call.  try renaming it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're inside a class, you need to pass a reference to WordPress for WordPress to call the function within the class. See the line that contains `$this`.

```
class My_Users {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'do_redirect', array( $this, 'redirect' ) );
    }

    public function redirect() {
        $url = get_site_url( null, '/welcome', 'https' );
        wp_safe_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }


    public function some_function() {
        do_action( 'do_redirect' );
    }
}
$custom_users = new My_Users();
$custom_users->some_function();
```

That being said, you do not need to use an action here. It would be simpler to just do the following:

```
class My_Users {
    public function redirect() {
        $url = get_site_url( null, '/welcome', 'https' );
        wp_safe_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
$custom_users = new My_Users();
$custom_users->redirect();
```