# AJAX button run function

Tags: plugins, functions, ajax

I want after click button run function, . All is in one class.

**JQUERY**

```
jQuery('#text2').click(function() {

    var data = {
        'action': 'myfunction',
        'whatever': $button.data('text2'), 
    };   

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
      public function myfunction() {

       $write = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

       $write++;

       echo $write;
       wp_die();

      }
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="text2" value="1500"> test </button>
```

Comment: This is not how AJAX requests in WordPress work. Check out [the Plugin Handbook  on AJAX](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/) - or even better [the REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work as you expect, you need to add the following lines in your constructor (depending on the requirements you have)

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myfunction', array($this, 'myfunction') );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myfunction', array($this, 'myfunction') );
```

Note that `wp_ajax_nopriv_myfunction` executes for users that are not logged in. The other executes for logged in users only.

You also need to just check that in your JS, `ajaxurl` returns your ajax URL.

If not, you'll need to expose that URL for usage in your JS. You can do that by following the codex here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

You will need to call `wp_die();` at the end of your PHP function as well.

Comment: Constructors are a bad place for adding actions, see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/48094).

Comment: @kero That answer was in regards to instantiating a class via a hook. In the example above, we are calling the hook within the class as given in the first example of the above answer you referred us to.

Comment: When i write data and have many the same buttons, if I click one, then other not work, probably by wp_die(). How solve this?

Comment: @polyman Unsure what you mean I'm afraid. Can you give an example?